# difference between addonGlobalLayoutListener and addOnPreDrawListener

Tags: android, android-view

We know [ViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html) is used to register listeners that can be notified of global changes in the view tree. There are two method defined in this class are 
`addOnGlobalLayoutListener(ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` listener) and `addOnPreDrawListener(ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener listener)`. But the the purpose of these methods are not clearly understandable to me which described in the developer site. I tried to understand it and also searched in google but was unable to find clear picture about this topic. Any help is greatly handful  for me.

Answer (score 9):

```
OnPreDrawListener
```

Gets called just before onDraw() method gets invoked.  At this point, all views in the tree have been measured and given a frame. Therefore you can properly manipulate view in this callback

```
OnGlobalLayoutListener
```

This listener gets called:
- when visibility state changes. In example when view has been drawn it becomes visible and this gets called.
- when you addView state of view tree changes